# How to prompt when sending to an external email address?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want a warning every time I try to send an email outside my company, where external email addresses are those that don't end in the `mycompany.com` domain.

This prompts every time I send an email, regardless of the recipient or recipients.

It should only prompt if at least one of the to/cc/bcc recipients has an email address with a different domain.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim i As Long
Dim xRecipientAddress As String
Dim xPrompt As String
Dim xYesNo As Integer
Dim xPos As Integer
On Error Resume Next
If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
Set xMailItem = Item
Set xRecipients = xMailItem.Recipients
For i = xRecipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    xRecipientAddress = xRecipients.Item(i).Address
    xPos = InStrRev(LCase(xRecipientAddress), "@mycompany.com")
    If xPos <= 0 Then Exit For
    Cancel = False
Next
If InStrRev(LCase(xRecipientAddress), "@mycompany.com") > 0 Then Exit Sub
xPrompt = "Are you sure you want to send this email outside of The Company?"
xYesNo = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "External Email Warning")
If xYesNo = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove OnErrorResumeNext, and handle errors instead. Break (F9) on your If statement, are the values as expected? Copy the Instrrev expression to evaluate it in the immediate toolwindow, tweak as needed.

Comment: Side note, this kind of warning can be handled with what's probably a GPO by your sysadmins, it shouldn't be a VBA macro doing this.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks, yeah, unfortunately our sysadmin isn't super knowledgeable (we're a small company and still working out the kinks in everything!) but I did suggest it. This is my stopgap until that gets implemented (I know it's very easy to do).

Answer (score 0):

The [Recipient.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) may not return an SMTP email address in case of Exchange accounts. Microsoft Exchange Server can operate with email address types such as Exchange, SMTP, X.400, Microsoft Mail, etc. By default, the `Address` property of the `Recipient` class returns just an Exchange type address, for example this one:

```
/O=ORGANIZATION_NAME /OU=EXCHANGE_GROUP /CN=RECIPIENTS /CN=USER_NAME
```

To get other address types, we need to find the recipient in the Outlook address book by using the `IAddrBook.ResolveName` method, then reach the `IMailUser` interface with the `IAddrBook.OpenEntry` method and get the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` property. Read more about that in the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article.

Also you may consider using the `AddressEntry` property of the `Recipient` class return an object which represents a person, group, or public folder to which the messaging system can deliver messages. You can check out the [AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.addressentryusertype) property which returns a constant from the `OlAddressEntryUserType` enumeration representing the user type of the `AddressEntry`. In case of Exchange entry you need to use the following sequence of property and method calls:

```
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

The [ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress) property returns a string representing the primary Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the `ExchangeUser`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic is easier to follow. I believe `InStr` is sufficient.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim xMailItem As MailItem
Dim xRecipients As Recipients
Dim i As Long

Dim xRecipientAddress As String
Dim xPrompt As String

Dim xYesNo As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim xPos As Long

If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

Set xMailItem = Item
Set xRecipients = xMailItem.Recipients

For i = xRecipients.count To 1 Step -1

    xRecipientAddress = xRecipients.Item(i).Address
    Debug.Print xRecipientAddress
    
    ' Use text from internal xRecipientAddress
    xPos = InStr(LCase(xRecipientAddress), "@mycompany.com")
    Debug.Print xPos
    
    If xPos = 0 Then
        xPrompt = "Are you sure you want to send this email outside of The Company?"
        xYesNo = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "External Email Warning")
        If xYesNo = vbNo Then Cancel = True
        Exit For
    End If
    
Next

End Sub
```